# Show $T(r, \theta) = (r\cos \theta , r \sin \theta)$ is surjective

Tags: multivariable-calculus

On $(0, 1] \times [0, 2 \pi)$. I have to set $r \cos \theta = x$ and $r \sin \theta = y$ and solve for $r$ and $\theta$. So I get $\theta = \cos^{-1}(\frac{x}{r})$ and $\theta = \sin^{-1}(\frac{x}{r})$ but I don't see how this shows surjectivity for both $r$ and $\theta$. What should I do now?

Comment: Could you stop repeatedly writing things like $r cos\theta$ and write $r\cos\theta$ instead?  That is standard.

Comment: Sovling for $r$ would mean finding that $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: Hint: square both sides and use that $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1$.

Comment: And, what is the codomain? You seem to be saying that the domain in $(0,1] \times [0,2 \pi)$, which will mean that $(0,0)$ is not in the image.

Comment: The codomain is the image of $(0,1] \times [0,2 \pi)$ under $T$.

Comment: Well, if the codomain is defined to be the image, then by definition the map is surjective. Are you sure this is what you mean?

Comment: Yes, the book says that this example is surjective trivially by definition, but I don't see why the definition implies it is surjective, according to how we algebraically solve equations to show surjectivity.

Comment: Look up the definition of surjectivity. And, while you're at it, the *precise* definition of the map $T$ including its domain and codomain. Without that, asking whether or $T$ is surjective (or injective, for that matter) is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the codomain if $T$ is surjective. Clearly, it is not surjective if the codomain is, for example, $\mathbb{R}^2$, though it is surjective on its image, which is $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 < x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$ (the disc with radius $1$ that has a hole in the origin). A mapping is always surjective if you take its image as codomain.

Comment: True, I was in a hurry and mixed the two things up (additionally, surjectivity does not make sense without a given codomain). Now it should be correct.